# how to show success or error message in bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML CODE:**

```
<li class="llogin">
   <a class="mlogin" data-target="#loginmodal" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>Login</a>
   <div class="modal" id="loginmodal" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name=username id="username" placeholder="username" value="" class="form-control" />
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name=password id="password" placeholder="password" value="" class="form-control" />
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="text-center" class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="submit" name="loginsubmit" id="loginsubmit" class="form-control btn btn-info" value="LogIn" style="width:20%">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div id="loginresult" class="alert-success"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

**AJAX CODE:**

```
$("#loginsubmit").click(function(){
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

 $.ajax({

    type:'POST',
    data: {username:username,password:password},
    url:'login.php',
    success:function(logged)
    {
        $("#loginresult").html(logged);
        $('#loginmodal').modal("show");

    },

 })
})
```

I am building web store using **PHP**.i want to show message in `bootstrap` modal but do not know what's going wrong in above code.

Please suggest me what changes should i do to achieve the desired behavior.

I am getting message without modal but i want to show message in modal.

Comment: Also post your PHP code so we can see what response is back from server?Will be easy to help.

Comment: @HikmatSijapati i have posted php code. please help to solve the problem